# What is the difference between $(var) and var?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

It came to my understanding that you can use a DOM element as jQuery selector e.g `$(document)`.
So why does the jQuery `attr()` function work in both these cases?

```
let v = $("#nodeID");
//First case
$(v).attr("href","www1"); //works
//Second case
v.attr("href","www2"); //also works
```

What's the difference?

Comment: both are same no difference on is assigned as reference.

Comment: @MurtazaHussain — You're wrong. `$(v)` doesn't create a reference to `v` (or to the same object as `v` is already a reference to)

Comment: `v` is already a jquery object so you don't need to `$(v)` again (unless you mean to clone it)

Comment: Re your deleted question with `e`s: Good screenshot. That's the name of the constructor function used to create the object you were looking at. The name suggests you're looking at the result of minified code, but you can see the same format if you do this in the Chrome console: `function e() { } new e;` You'll see `e { }` in the output. (BTW, in a comment on the question, you *seem* to think I downvoted the question. I didn't. It's often the case that the person commenting is **not** the person downvoting.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder indeed it's a minified version, and I'm using  'prettify' in the 'sources' in 'dev tools'. Thank's a lot man, really helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pass a jQuery object to `$`, it will return a jQuery object containing the same elements as in the original jQuery object you passed. They're basically the same (though the objects are not `===`). You can nest jQuery objects in `$` as much as you want, it won't make a difference, it's just odd to do.

```js
$($($('div'))).text('foo');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many different kinds of value you can pass to the jQuery function. In this case you are passing [a jQuery selection](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-selection) about which the documentation says:

> selection
>   Type: jQuery
>   An existing jQuery object to clone.

So you are cloning `var`.

In this context, it is entirely pointless. (It can be useful if you were going to mutate the value but needed to preserve the original to use elsewhere).